# Как убрать пустоту внизу на форме

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

В конструкторе выглядит так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При запуске приложения так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не пойму от куда берется такое пространство

Настройки окна:

```
      <Window x:Class="Fields_RST.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Fields_RST"  
    mc:Ignorable="d"      
     Height="800" Width="1500" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowState="Maximized" 
    ResizeMode="NoResize" 
    WindowStyle="None"
    Background="#FFF3EECD">
```

Настройки формы:

```
<Grid Height="775" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Background="#FFF3EECD" Margin="0,25,0,0">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="631*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="553*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <RowDefinition Height="190*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--Окно-->

    <Grid Name="ToolBar" Grid.Row="0" Background="Transparent" MouseDown="ToolBar_MouseDown"  Margin="1,-25,2,775" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" >
        <Polygon Fill="white" Opacity="0.3"
         Points="107,0,
         115,7,
         249,7
         257,0"/>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <Button x:Name="Close" Click="Close_Click" Height="22" Width="22" Style="{StaticResource CloseBut}">
                <Image Height="20" Width="26"    Source="/Source/cross.png"    />
            </Button>
            <!--<Image Height="25" Width="25" Source="Properties/Source/Source/icons8-свернуть-окно-50.png" MouseDown="Image_MouseDown_1"/>-->
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

Можете подсказать, пожалуйста как нормально все организовать, у меня бардак, хочу сделать свой ToolBar,но какие-то изменения и все на форме лезет куда не надо

Comment: Потому что вы все гвоздями прибиваете, например вот `Margin="1,-25,2,775"`, что это за бешенные значения? Хотите, чтоб объект был сверху, установите ему `VerticalAlignment`. Не используйте конструктор, запустите ваше приложение, и пишите сами, руками XAML, с использованием сеток, панелей, и др. элементов позиционирования, будет тогда все как надо. Вот сразу, если видите в проекте гвоздями прибитые `Width` и `Height`, видите огромные `Margin`, видите что-то по типу `631*` - все, значит сразу что-то не так.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ,поняла, спасибо)

Comment: Не использовать задание высоты и ширины. Чтобы нормально помочь с разметкой, надо видеть [воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), а не куски разметки, вырванные из контекста. То есть чтобы например я мог взять XAML, вставить в пустое приложение и увидеть вашу проблему.